# Find monitor configuration in terms of Screens Wide x Screens High

Tags: c#, .net, screen, multiple-monitors

I'm looking at the Screen class to find out how many monitors wide a desktop is. If there we say a 3x1 configuration of monitors (A pretty standard configuation) I'd want to get 3 and 1, in a Rectangle.

If it were a 2x2 configuration of monitors (Less standard) I'd want 2 and 2 in a Rectangle.

I'm not interested in the resolution of these monitors, just the physical matrix of how they're arranged.

EDIT: I've thought that if I get the total working area, and then using each individual screen try to find a configuration that would fit, then I would be left with the physical amount of screens in the system. Thoughts?

Comment: What if there are two, positioned top left and bottom right of a square with no common edge?

Comment: Hm, well, I could still represent them as two side-by-side. It's more so that the user knows where the boundaries of one monitor begin and end.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could use the `Bounds` property of the `Screen` objects ? (end up with something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/GBzVQ.png))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *could* work:

```
var width = Screen.AllScreens.Select(s => s.Bounds.X).Distinct().Count();
var height = Screen.AllScreens.Select(s => s.Bounds.Y).Distinct().Count();
```

Note:  I tested this with multiple monitors that are identical in every way.